# Simplifying an if (do some operation) then return

Tags: java, if-statement, coding-style, refactoring, code-cleanup

This probably a common occurrence and might be a stupid question, but i just really want to know how others handle this.

say i have:

```
private void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
     String text = textfield.getText();
     if(isValid(text)){
         // do something eg:
         list.add(text);
     }
}

private boolean isValid(String text){
    if(text.isEmpty()){
      displayErrorMessage("empty string!");
      return false;
    }
    if(hasInvalidChars(text)){
      displayErrorMessage("Invalid chars");
      return false;
    }
    ....
    return true;
}
```

the isValid(String) method feels weird, I think a method should only do one simple thing, but isValid() certainly violates it, it displays an error message then returns a boolean.

Is that alright? or are there other ways to get around it?

The other not so elegant workaround that i could think of was to implement a flag. ie:

```
private void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
       String text = textfield.getText();
       verify(text);

       if(!errorIsDisplayed){
          list.add(text);
       }   
}

private boolean verify(String text){
    if(text.isEmpty()){
      displayErrorMessage("empty string!");
      errorIsDisplayed = true;
    }
    if(hasInvalidChars(text)){
      displayErrorMessage("Invalid chars");
      errorIsDisplayed = true;
    }
    ....
    errorIsDisplayed = false;
}
```

I hope you can clearly see the problem that i was trying to solve, I think there is a simple solution that I'm missing, maybe due to the lack of sleep and the weather, I don't know. How would others implement this?

Comment: Instead of displaying the messages inside the method, you could display them outside based on what isValid returns, but then you wouldn't be able to differentiate between your two cases there. Is there a problem with what you currently have other than that it feels weird?

Comment: yes, that's my current point of action, moving the implementation of isValid() inside the actionPerformed() itself. I just felt like actionPerformed() would clutter. I think having a method like isValid() would somehow make the more code readable while showing the intent.

Answer (score 1):

If you like,
 you can define an `enum` of error type and the method `isValid` just return the type.

```
enum Type{
    VALID("Valid"),
    EMPTY("Empty String"),
    // other types.

    public final String message;
}
```

For a certain text string, you can define a method `getType` to get its corresponding Type.

`Type getType(String text){...}`

Then your `isValid` method should only check if this message is valid.

```
boolean isValid(Type type){
    return type == Type.VALID;
}
```

And in `actionPerformed` you can take actions according to the Type of a text string.

```
actionPerformed(...){
    String text = ...
    Type type = getType(text);
    if (isValid(type)){
        //Actions for valid text
    } else {
        //Actions for invalid text
        System.out.println(type.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good point, but I don't think it caters my specific problem. I want to move all invalid operations on a separate block so I can handle the valid one's on a nice simple block, away from the logic of invalids.

Comment: if i would take Type isValid()'s enum, then it doesn't really differ from doing the entire if then else of invalids inside actionPerformed() directly then the final else clause would be for the valid statement, something like that.

another not so elegant solution was to introduced a flag, a flag to toggle along with the displaying a message, then there wouldn't be a need to get the return of isValid() and just check if the flag is set.

Comment: Not agree. You can get the type of this message from another method, say `getType(arg:String):Type` and change `isValid(arg:String)` to `isValid(arg:Type):boolean` and this `isValid` will only check if this message is valid or not. If not, you can print the message. And logically, I think you can not omit all the if statements. I think this solution will be much more readable than your original one. BTW, thanks for your feedback. : )

Comment: Eh...You can think this enum class as your `flag` but I think it is more `object-oriented`?

Comment: I think in your "flag" solution, your methods are tightly coupled with a global variable `errorIsDisplayed`. So it is not elegant. I do think that two methods interacting on return values is more elegant than depending on some variables outside of  method scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, pass in a parameter of `List<String> unacceptableReasons` to `isValid()` and add the error messages to it. And keep returning the boolean.
The `actionPerformed()` can take on the responsibilities to display the messages.

The solution with the field `errorIsDisplayed` is harder to understand and makes up for less readable code IMO.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with everything you said, flag is not the solution, i just put it there make the point, or illustrate my problem further. I want to avoid all that too, what do you suggest?

Comment: See the first paragraph of my answer.